# Content types on "Add Content" randomly re-sort themselves

Tags: 8

Does anyone know why sometimes the content types on "node/add" in the admin will list differently every so often?

Example, say I have Article, Job, Page, Product, Resource, Webform. Sometimes they are listed alphabetically (**preferred**), but I just noticed after creating some content, some of the items are out of order - Drupal 8.2.7.

Comment: Not sure what is going on here but perhaps an update to 8.3 fixes the issue? Worth testing without spending time debugging because you need to update anyway.

Comment: There is no particular order, but normally they should come out of the config storage sorted by the machine name, which can be different from the displayed name, especially if it's modified or translated. If you want a sorted list, you would have to override `NodeController::addPage`. Don't think that there is a change between 8.2 and 8.3.

Comment: Hm, weird. Just a vanilla 8.2.7 site.

Comment: I don't know if they have to be sorted by machine name, but usually they are. You can test this with drush, I've put this in an answer, because it is to long for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can check in which order the content types are loaded from the configuration storage with drush:

```
drush ev "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node_type')->loadMultiple()))"
```